# Integration of Product of Natural Logarithm

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

Was solving the Non-Homogeneous Linear Differential Equation given below:

$$x^2\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}-5x\frac{dy}{dx}+9y=6x^3\ln{x} $$

Got the complementary function to be: $y_c=(c_1+c_2\ln{x})x^3$

But I got stuck when trying to get the particular integral using variation of parameters. I got the following:

$$w_1=-6\int \frac{\ln{x}\ln{x}}{x}dx$$

and

$$w_1=6\int \frac{\ln{x}}{x}dx$$

Where the particular integral is assumed to be $y_p=w_1x^3+w_2x^3\ln{x}$

Please I need assistance in evaluating the values for $w$

Comment: Substitute $u=\ln x$.

Comment: Thanks @Guy, I didn't try that route. You've made my day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Substitute $u=\ln(x)$ and $\text{d}u=\frac{1}{x}\space\text{d}x$:
   $$\text{w}_1=\int\frac{\ln^2(x)}{x}\space\text{d}x=\int u^2\space\text{d}u=\frac{u^3}{3}+\text{C}=\frac{\ln^3(x)}{3}+\text{C}$$
2. Substitute $u=\ln(x)$ and $\text{d}u=\frac{1}{x}\space\text{d}x$:
   $$\text{w}_2=\int\frac{\ln(x)}{x}\space\text{d}x=\int u\space\text{d}u=\frac{u^2}{2}+\text{C}=\frac{\ln(x)}{2}+\text{C}$$